# Bind ObservableCollection to ItemsControls or ListView doesn't working

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In a UWP project I have: 1 page, 1 usercontrol and 1 viewmodel.

The page contain a SplitView with the user control loaded in pane:

```
<SplitView.Pane>
    <local:MyUserControl />
</SplitView.Pane>
```

Both page and user control have the same datacontext : the view model (called MyPageViewModel). The ViewModel have an ObservableCollection of object like:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Commands { get; set; }
```

In the page code-behind on a button click event, i create a List:

```
List<MyModel> ListCommands;
```

Where I load some datas, then I directly call a method from the ViewModel like:

```
(this.DataContext as MyPageViewModel).Load(listCommands);
```

Load is a method defined in the View Model, it fills the ObservableCollection:

```
public void Load(List<MyModel> commands)
    {
        Commands = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>(commands);
    }
```

This ObservableCollection is successfully loaded at runtime but the ItemsControl in the User Control don't display datas (as if the user interface wasn't notified changes occured), in the user control code:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:RestaurantDetailsViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

...

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}"
                  Grid.Row="1" />
```

The ItemsControl stay empty (I use a DataTemplate for display inner MyModel property). I tested with a ListView too but the result is the same.

Notes: My viewmodel inherit from a custom class that implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class MyPageViewModel : BindabelBase

public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName()]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            storage = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about ViewModels INotifyProperty implementation?

Comment: Oh sorry for this missing detail, I edited.

Comment: ok, so you have INotifyImplemented, but not used ;) try -  private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _commands; public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Commands { ger {return _commands;} set {_commnads = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Commands"); }

Comment: Yes, i didn't mentionned but i already tried by using INotify :

private ObservableCollection<Commande> _commands;
        public ObservableCollection<Commande> CommandsToPay
        {
            get { return _commands; }
            set
            {
                _commands = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CommandsToPay");
            }
        }

I place a breakpoint in set, it pass correctly but UI doesn't care.

Comment: How is it that the page and usercontrol have the same context?  It appears that your user control is creating a new instance of the viewmodel.   If they are different, you are populating the page's vm collection, but rendering the user control's vm collection - which is not changing.

Comment: I just noticed that too. I' m searching for a solution to that problem.

Comment: Ok, finally it works, i just set parent's DataContext to usercontrol :

<local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=CommandesPage}" />

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all quick answers, the problem is solved.

My error was to redeclare the DataContext for both page and usercontrol tat created an new instance of the ViewModel (= data context wasn't the same for page and user control, two différents instances).

The solution was to indicate page's datacontext to the user control like this :

```
<local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=CommandesPage}" />
```

where CommandesPage is the name of the page.